# Variadic function to find the first matching (string) argument in a larger array

Tags: c++, strings, parsing, search, c++17

Playing around with parsing a data buffer I wrote a small search function to find the first complete match out of a set of (string) arguments.

The (simplified) buffer class with the find function:

```
// buffer_simple.hpp
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, size_t S>
class buffer {
public:
    constexpr buffer() {}
    template <size_t Si>
    constexpr buffer(const T (&arr)[Si]) {
        for (size_t i = 0, l = (S < Si ? S : Si); i < l; ++i) {
            values[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find the first matching array in a larger array and return the argument index and buffer end index of the match.
     * @param   str One or many strings to search for
     * @returns std::pair<argument index, end of match index in buffer>
     */
    template <size_t... SS>
    constexpr std::pair<int, size_t> find_first(const T (&...str)[SS]) const {
        size_t matching[] { (SS - 1)... }; // Amount of remaining 'characters to match'
        for (size_t i = 0; i < S; ++i) { // Loop over the dataset
            int mi = 0;
            ((matching[mi++] = (str[(SS - 1) - matching[mi]] == values[i]) ? (matching[mi] - 1) : ((str[0] == values[i]) ? (SS - 2) : (SS - 1) )), ...); // Nasty pseudo loop for width first search
            for (mi = 0; mi < sizeof...(SS); ++mi) { // See if we have any full matches
                if (matching[mi] == 0) return { mi, i };
            }
        }
        return { -1, 0 };
    }

    constexpr T& operator[](const size_t i) { return values[i]; }
    constexpr const T& operator[](const size_t i) const { return values[i]; }
private:
    T values[S] {0};
};
```

An example use case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "buffer_simple.hpp"

buffer<char, 256> b { "find mefind me:gehoehgioewghowieanother string:" };

int main () {
    const auto result = b.find_first("find me:", "bla", "another string:");
    // switch (result.first) {
    // case 0:
    //     break;
    // case 1:
    //     break;
    // case 2:
    //     break;
    // }
    std::cout << "Result index: " << result.first << ", offset: " << result.second << std::endl;
}
```

This will return:

`Result index: 0, offset: 14`

Despite the extremely nasty fold expression this actually works. During runtime that is. As a test I tried declaring the buffer and search result constexpr and things blew up with GCC reporting an `Array out of bounds` error. I'm curious to see which other pitfalls might be lurking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good stuff!

I only see one big issue (which is actually what's preventing you from using this as a `constexpr`).

**Errors:**

**UB: Unsequenced modification**

```
matching[mi++] = (str[(SS - 1) - matching[mi]]
         ^^                               ^^
```

Which value does `mi` take for that second indexing? The C++ standard says: either the pre or post increment value is legal. You have undefined behavior here.

You can solve this by separating out the `mi` incrementation as a separate statement. Using the evil comma operator would allow you to do it as a fairly small modification of your existing code:

```
(
  ((matching[mi] = (str[(SS - 1) - matching[mi]] == values[i])
     ? (matching[mi] - 1) 
     : ((str[0] == values[i]) ? (SS - 2) : (SS - 1))
  ), ++mi), 
...);
```

This actually makes the constexpr version work!

**Style**

1. I think `find_first` should be a free-floating function, since you already have the `[]` accessors.
2. I would definitely try to format that fold expression in a more readable manner. See my version of it above for an example.

**Improvements**

3. Add a template deduction guide:

Something like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t LEN>
buffer(const T(&)[LEN]) -> buffer<T, LEN>;
```

So then your declare buffers in a cleaner manner, and have the buffer be perfectly sized:

```
buffer<char, 256> b { "find mefind me:gehoehgioewghowieanother string:" };
//becomes
buffer b { "find mefind me:gehoehgioewghowieanother string:" };
```

Comment: Fascinating, for me this was an exercise in seeing what can be done with fold expressions. I didn't know it was possible to add a second statement (the increment) in that way. Cool! About 2: The formatting is indeed nasty, no disagreement there (though not that hard to reason about). About 1: It's actually part of much larger generic buffer class for MCUs and the like, the whole thing would make this function hard to find, so I just shortened it and removed the extra indices for the moving access window the original buffer class has.

Comment: @Stefan Fair enough. I clearly do not have the ful picture of the context, so whatever makes the most sense for your codebase.

Comment: About 3: It's not really needed, I just dropped in this constructor and hard-coded string to have workable example here, in my use case I'd always start with an empty buffer which will be filled with incoming serial, radio packages or similar data. Fitting the buffer would be the opposite of what I want (which is to be able to send YAML-like data for easy debugging purposes).

Comment: @Stefan Considering you cared about having a compile-time version of this being functional, it felt like something you would really want.

Answer (score 1):

To build on Frank's answer...

---

```
#pragma once
```

Be aware of the pitfalls of `#pragma once`.  Despite the widespread support of `#pragma once`, the compiler extension is non-standard (rejected by committee) and not guaranteed to have the same behavior across all supported compilers.  The `#pragma once` extension allows the compiler to figure out which files should and should not be read for compilation. This is a difficult task and can easily be defeated by symlinks/build systems.  The `#include` guard idiom forces you to decide on an identifier that defines your intent the file you are working with.  It does require a unique name and you do have to type it out twice across three lines, but you control what is included and not included.  Until the Modules TS is standardized (*soon<sup>tm</sup>*) or [another approach](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0538r0.html) becomes standardized, prefer the `#include` guard idiom.

---

```
template <typename T, size_t S>
```

`size_t` is not guaranteed to be defined.  Prefer the qualified `std::size_t` which is guaranteed to be defined by the C++ standard.

---

```
    constexpr buffer() {}
```

Use `= default;` to be explicit to readers that your intent is to use the default semantics.  By defining a user-written default constructor (`{}`), `buffer` becomes a non-aggregate and is therefore non-trivial.  The user-written default constructor also has an empty exception specification, whereas the compiler-generated default constructor would have an implicitly generated exception specification.

---

```
    constexpr buffer(const T (&arr)[Si]) {
```

When reading from non-owning references to character sequences, prefer [`std::basic_string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) and friends.  They provide simple and safe access to character sequences independently from how the sequence is allocated/stored.

---

```
    constexpr std::pair<int, size_t> find_first(const T (&...str)[SS]) const {
```

You should also prefer to return a `std::basic_string_view` to the found buffered substring.

---

```
        for (size_t i = 0, l = (S < Si ? S : Si); i < l; ++i) {
            values[i] = arr[i];
        }
```

Prefer [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) as it's self-documenting and will appropriately use bulk copy instructions like `memcopy`/`memmove` instead of multiple individual assignments.

---

```
    T values[S] {0};
```

Prefer `std::array` as they are pretty much zero-cost safety wrappers around fixed-sized C arrays with additional functionality.

---

Instead of implementing a naive search, have you considered using a constexpr boyer moore search?